# Fastest way to check if Action/(FSharpFunc) captures outer state

Tags: .net, .net-core, f#

What is the fastest way to check if an FSharpFunc (or in general anonymous delegates) capture outer scope ?

Reflections works but is something I'd like to avoid for performance and maintainability reasons.

Example:

```ml
[<EntryPoint>]
let main(args: string[]) =
    let count = 1
             
    // func captures outer variable count
    let capturesState = fun args -> count |> ignore
    capturesState args
    0
```

Comment: Move the function to an unrelated scope, and see if it still compiles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is currently no way of doing this without reflection. This is the solution I came up with and it works pretty well. Had no issues with it so far, but keep in mind that it's no bullet proof and there might be some edge cased I did not think about.

**How does it work ?**

Consider the following function 'a' that captures state.

```ml
let o = "o" // non static!

// function captures outer variable 'o'
let a = (fun () ->
    printf "%s" o
)
```

The function we bind to 'a' is turned into a compiler generated class that contains the actual code in a method called 'Invoke'. If the function does not capture state then it has a parameterless constructor. It does not need anything that's not passed into invoke. BUT if it captures state the class will have a Constructor taking < 1 parameters. This is what we will use to determine if a function captures state.

Also, because performance is a concern we cache the result of the analysis.

This is what the code looks like:

```ml
module FunctionAnalysis =
    open System
    open System.Reflection
    open System.Collections.Concurrent

    let internal cache = ConcurrentDictionary<Type, bool>()

    let private flags =
        BindingFlags.Instance |||
        BindingFlags.NonPublic |||
        BindingFlags.Public

    let capturesState (func : 'a) : bool =
        let type' = func.GetType()

        let hasValue, value = cache.TryGetValue type'

        match hasValue with
        | true -> value
        | false ->
            let capturesState =
                type'.GetConstructors(flags)
                |> Array.map (fun info -> info.GetParameters().Length)
                |> Array.exists (fun parameterLength -> parameterLength > 0)

            cache.AddOrUpdate(type', capturesState, (fun identifier lastValue -> capturesState))
```